# Exception Handling in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I would like to handle my own exceptions in Rails 3. What is the best process to handle custom exceptions and routing errors in Rails 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle your custom exceptions as follows:
In application controller, add follwing:

```
rescue_from Exception, :with => :handle_exception

  def not_found
    render :template => "shared/not_found", :status => 404
  end

  private
  def handle_exception(exception)
    case exception
    when CanCan::AccessDenied
      authenticate_user!
    when ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      not_found
    else
      internal_server_error(exception)
    end
  end

  def internal_server_error(exception)
    render :template => "shared/internal_server_error", :status => 500
  end
```

Now in your method, you can raise error or exception as:

```
def method_name
  # raise exception_name, "message on exception"
  raise ArgumentError, "missing some param"
end
```

You can also catch routing errors by adding route as follows:

```
match "*any", :to => "application#not_found"
```

Note: You should add the above route at end in your route.rb